# Encrypty property in a Farm propery bag

Tags: property-bag

I'm using [SharePoint Property Bag Settings 2013](https://pbs2013.codeplex.com/workitem/13440) to set my property bag.
I would like to encrypt a password at farm level in it.
So from Central Administration/System Settings I tried to set an encrypted property.

Unlike property bags at site or list scope, no encrypt flag is available.
Do you know if there is any reason for that or I'm doing something wrong?

[image]